# Remove debug apk files from device

Tags: android

I'm testing tv apk on my chromecast with google tv 4k. I have maybe 4 other apps installed. After few rounds of debugging android studio said it is not able to install debug app because there is no free space. So i removed one app, but then again after few rounds of debugging it is saying that free space is over and it can't install the app. How can i free space that nothing is using, why it thinks there is no space while only installed/remove app was debug apk i was testing? Removing app does not help, now i have to remove the app that i'm debugging before even being able to run another debug build.